# How to get bash to check for the location of a file?

Tags: php, linux, bash

I want my bash script to find where PHP is installed - this will be used on different Linux servers, and some of them won't be able to use the `which` command. I need help with that second line:

```
#!/bin/bash
if (php is located in /usr/bin/php); then
    PHP = /usr/bin/php
else
    PHP = /usr/local/zend/bin/php
fi
$PHP script.php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
if [ -e /usr/bin/php ]; then
```

Answer (score 4):

Use this:

```
`which php`
```

But this is what **I** would do:

```
#!/bin/env php
<?php

require 'script.php';
```

Comment: You said to use `which php` in spite of the original post saying some wouldn't be able to have access to `which`. Also, you might have misread the question. He is trying to execute a PHP script through the command line, but in order to do that he needs the path to the PHP executable. How would a PHP `require` help him if he can't execute it?

Comment: Hi Derek. Since you downvoted me for including "which", you should see that I provided both answers.  Pretty much every single UNIX distribution has /bin/env, and  using that will find PHP's location in the path much like 'which', but not requiring it.  Also, the `require` is there to show him how to include the file in his example.

Comment: I understand that but the original poster wanted a command-line solution. Also, I'm new to Unix but perhaps you meant to use `/usr/bin/env`? I tried Ubuntu and Mac OS X and neither has `env` in `/bin`, only `/usr/bin`. But you are correct, `env php script.php` should work, I just tested it as well. I cannot change my vote however; it is locked.

Answer (score 2):

Bash has a `type` command.

```
type -p php
```

will give you the location of the executable based on your `$PATH`.

You have spaces around your equal signs which Bash doesn't allow. This is what your command should look like:

```
PHP=$(type -p php)
```

or you could even execute it directly:

```
$(type -p php) script.php
```

Answer (score 0):

whereis php locates it

Comment: The whereis command doesn't work for /usr/local/zend/bin/php ...not sure why, but it may be because it was installed from a tar.gz that just ran a crude bash install program

Comment: whereis, if I remember right, will only look in your current PATH variable for the executable you are looking for.  

Most standard paths include /usr/bin /bin and if you are root: /usr/sbin and /sbin.  Since in this case you have php in a special directory whereis likely won't find it unless you have a modified PATH variable.

You can check by typing echo $PATH

Answer (score 0):

For short piece of code you can use: `&&` and `||`

```
[ -x /usr/bin/php ] && PHP=/usr/bin/php || PHP=/usr/local/zend/bin/php
```

BTW
`-x` return true if the file is executable
`-e` return true if the file exists